# missing 1 required positional argument: 'source', trying to get discord bot to play paused audio

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Getting

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: VoiceClient.play() missing 1 required positional argument: ' source'
```

and do not understand what i am doing wrong

here is the code

```
@client.command(pass_contect = True)
async def resume(ctx):
   voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
   if voice.is_paused():
        voice.play()
        await ctx.send("Audio has been paused")
   else:
        await ctx.send("no audio is playing.")
```

the pause code is working without any problems

```
@client.command(pass_contect = True)
async def pause(ctx):
   voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
   if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
   else:
        await ctx.send("no audio is playing.")
```

was trying to get the discord bot to resume playing a paused audio

Comment: Hi, please read the error. `voice.play()` needs an argument `source`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us what library you're using, assuming you're using [Wavelink](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wavelink.html#wavelink.Player.play), you need to use `voice.resume()` instead of `voice.play()` with no parameters.

If you aren't using Wavelink, consult the correct documentation.

Comment: these are the libraries i am using
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import requests
import json